# Net Core 2.0 - slow response times when deployed. Always 100ms+

Tags: asp.net, .net, postgresql, docker, asp.net-core

I have just deployed really first dev version of my api on my VPS to allow my frontend guy access it easily.

My setup is so far pretty simple - .NET Core 2.0 (API, JWT access control) + PostgreSQL.

Even for simple request with empty body to registration endpoint, I am getting response times about 100ms or even more. On localhost(not in Docker) it's much better - about 8-15ms for the same test.

Both application and db are in docker containers behind the nginx proxy on 4core/8gb VPS so it should not be an issue.

Some issue with docker configuration? I though it's something related to db, but as it's slow even on model validation when it does not call db at all it's something else...

I will appreciate any help...

Comment: Shouldn't you direct this question to your provider? Usually VPS don't get dedicated CPUs, just vCPUs. We don't know where its located and where you are located and not even how its virtualized. Running Docker inside Hosts which are virtualized themselves isn't quite supported and can be slow, i.e. HostEurope usually runs their VPS inside Linux containers. When you run docker inside that, then well, its not so good

Comment: I have KVM VPS, so it's virtualized but I have dedicated resources. Other apps running well

Comment: Try to use https://miniprofiler.com/. Add counters and get info about where are your delays comes from(db/viewrender/controller code)

Comment: It ended up as an issues with: (only a little effect) nginx workers changed to auto from 1; (much higher impact) disabling cloudfare protection. Now response times in country where server is located are at 20ms level and from other countries about 40-60ms which is totally ok.
It was not an issue with VPS at all.